# HotKey to Play/Pause HTML5 Music Player

Tags: jquery, html, hotkeys

This a small portion of the javascript code I used for an HTML5 music player. I was wondering if you guys can help me build a HotKey to toggle the Play/Pause button using the Space key. Any ideas?

CODE:

```
   $('.trackslist li').live('click', function(event) {

    var $track = $(this),
        $player = $track.closest('.player'),
        trackId = $track.data('sc-track').id,
        play = $player.is(':not(.playing)') || $track.is(':not(.active)');

    if (play) { onPlay($player, trackId); }else{ onPause($player); }

    $track.addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');

    return false;

  });

    $('.next').live('click', function(event) {
        $player = $(this).closest('.player');
        onNext($player);
    });

    $('.prev').live('click', function(event) {
        $player = $(this).closest('.player');
        onPrev($player);
    });
```

An idea I found:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){

    var ev = isIE?event:e;
    if(ev.charCode && ev.charCode == 32)
        player.playPause();
    else{
        switch(ev.keyCode){
            case 32:
                player.playPause();
                break;
            case 39:
                player.nextSong();
                break;
            case 37:
                player.prevSong();
                break;
            case 38:
                player.volumeInc();
                break;
            case 40:
                player.volumeDec();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code for the `keydown` event on the `document` element, the `player` variable is not set to anything.

Also jQuery normilizes the `e.keyCode` and `e.charCode` properties with `e.which` but that is only if you bind to the event using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    var key    = event.which,//get charCode of event
        player = $('audio');//get the player (I'm assuming it's an `audio` tag)

    switch(ev.keyCode){
        case 32:
            player.playPause();
            break;
        case 39:
            player.nextSong();
            break;
        case 37:
            player.prevSong();
            break;
        case 38:
            player.volumeInc();
            break;
        case 40:
            player.volumeDec();
            break;
    }

});
```

I noticed that `trackId = $track.data('sc-track').id` probably isn't actually getting the ID of the `$track` element, try one of these:

```
trackId = $track.data('sc-track')//this will get the `data-sc-track` attribute for this element
```

OR

```
trackId = $track[0].id//this will get the ID of this element
```

One last note, `.live()` has been depreciated as of jQuery 1.7. You should be using `.delegate()` if you are using an older version and `.on()` if you are using jQuery 1.7 or greater.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/on*

Comment: So there's no way I can do this?

Comment: @RickyCortes You need to retrieve a reference to the player inside of the `keydown` event handler so that you can pause or play it.

Comment: Oh okay well the bottom code is just something related I found. It has nothing to do with the top code.

Comment: @RickyCortes So what have you tried and what is the problem? Do you have a live version I can see?

Comment: Got you.. Well that's very helpful. Thanks bro!

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm barely working on this player.